# Is this reputation cap calculated correctly?

Tags: support, reputation

Today I saw my reputation go down and up with a strange behavior. Then I got the following:

[image]

> I shouldn't have **217** but **215**. 200 for "normal" reputation (capped) + 15 for the accepted answer. Maybe this is something you wanted to be aware of.

I think it has something to do with down votes I got after cap was reached, then got new reputation point, and now new cap is calculated incorrectly.

**UPDATE**: I did something unusual. I deleted one of my [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33986/software-consultancy-or-in-house-developement/33990#33990) (link) that got 4 upvotes and one downvote (the answer did not answer the question at all). Maybe this *case* is so specific (cap + deleted question with up/down votes + accepted answer) ?

Comment: Did you accept an answer on one of your own questions?

Comment: No, that would have been listed in the screenshot (I clicked on Reputation to have the details)

Comment: Perhaps you got a +2 bonus for a good answer to a really bad question?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you compared that against [this link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/reputation)? There are sometimes lags ...

Comment: Is the reputation calculated is the **real** one?

Comment: @Pierre , it shows you your current _actual_ reputation, and how you earned it, blow by blow. This might not match the reputation that you see under your name, it merely shows you what your real rep would be if it were recalculated.

Comment: @Pierre - for instance, say you answered a question and received 5 up votes, then the question was migrated to another site. Your _actual_ rep would be 50 less than what you see under your name.